# Suppressing margin citations in tufte-book

Tags: citing, tufte

I'm writing a book in *tufte-book*, in which bibliographic citations (*\cite{}*) are rendered small in the adjacent page margin and alphabetically at normal size in the bibliography.  This is a lovely, elegant and very readable style.

However, the last section of each chapter is on bibliographic and historical discussions in which every paragraph may have 10 or more citations.  This is simply too many to appear in the margins.  Hence I would like to use a traditional (natbib?) or other citation style *just for those final chapter sections*.  The citation information should appear in the text body as:  "... as has been discussed before (Jones and Smith, 2016)" and the Jones and Smith reference appear with all the entries in the bibliographic listing at the end of the book.

The ideal would be to create a new citation call:

```
\nomargincite{}
```

or

```
\cite2{}
```

that I would use just in those final chapter sections.

Alternatively, perhaps there is a way to create an environment such as:

```
\begin{nomargincite}

\end{nomargincite}
```

which would envelope just the text in those final sections.

I've seen reference to changing citation style *throughout* a tufte-book, but I need to employ *two* citation styles.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

Beginning chapter text\cite{Rodgers:16}

\section{Bibliographic remarks}

As has been discussed by many folk (\cite{JonesSmith:18}).

\bibliography{Art}  
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: While your question is understandable as it is right now, it would be much easier for me to get started if you could add a short example document with a few citations to your question (a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). That saves those trying to help you the pain of writing down a test document to demonstrate their answers and keeps them from guessing (maybe wrongly) certain things about your document (by default the `tufte` classes use `natbib`, but we don't know if you disabled that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a cheap solution: Use `\citep`. The `tufte` classes redefine `\cite` to give sidenote citations, but they don't define `natbib`'s commands `\citet` and `\citep`.

So `\citep` works a treat and even gives parentheses if you pass the `round` option to `natbib`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{round}{natbib}
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Pub},
  address   = {Place},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

Beginning chapter text\cite{appleby}

\section{Bibliographic remarks}
As has been discussed by many folk \citep{appleby}.


\bibliography{\jobname}  
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\end{document}
```

[image: As has been discussed by many folk (Appleby, 1980).]

Note that this only works if you use an `natbib`-author-year compatible style (as `plainnat` is one). It does in particular not work with the provided `tufte.bst`.

Comment: Wow that was fast!! (+1) . Let me try this on my big document and see if it works.  If so, I'll certainly accept.  (Might take an hour or so... other tasks intrude.)

Comment: You are good!  (Hence the 90.7k reputation!)  Worked like a charm.  (accept)